# How do Python dicts keep key order

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

Since Python 3.6 dictionaries keep insertion/key order.

I got into an argument with a colleague about HOW this is implemented. He says that this must have been achieved by using a list or some other collection to keep the key order. I suspect that there may be something more subtle at work.

I did the following comparisons:

```
# Python 3.4.3

d = {1: 2, 2:3, 3:4}
od = OrderedDict(d)

print(sys.getsizeof(d))   # 288
print(sys.getsizeof(od))  # 1304
```

```
# Python 3.6.3

d = {1: 2, 2:3, 3:4}

print(sys.getsizeof(d))   # 240
```

The size of `OderedDict` is enormous, I can absolutely see it using a list in the background for this task. However the size of regular dicts has not suffered any changes so I am skeptical about the fact that regular dicts also use lists to keep insertion order.

So HOW exactly do regular dicts in newer python versions keep key order?

Comment: You might be interested in this talk by Raymond Hettinger on the subject: https://youtu.be/p33CVV29OG8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a comment in the [`dict` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac75f6bdd4748b3378dd321f862d13aa1898f77a/Objects/dictobject.c#L89):

> Preserving insertion order
>
> It's simple for combined table.  Since dk_entries is mostly append only, we can get insertion order by just iterating dk_entries.

[and](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac75f6bdd4748b3378dd321f862d13aa1898f77a/Objects/dictobject.c#L17)

```
layout:

+---------------+
| dk_refcnt     |
| dk_log2_size  |
| dk_kind       |
| dk_usable     |
| dk_nentries   |
+---------------+
| dk_indices    |
|               |
+---------------+
| dk_entries    |
|               |
+---------------+
```

> dk_entries is array of PyDictKeyEntry.  Its size is USABLE_FRACTION(dk_size).
> DK_ENTRIES(dk) can be used to get pointer to entries.

So, it appears to maintain an array. More digging would need to be done though to get more information, but that's a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's an implementation detail. Python only specifies that a `dict` *does* remember key order, not *how* it does it.

Python 3.6 did not guarantee key order; that was an experimental re-implementation of the `dict` type in CPython. When (as expected) that experiment was deemed a success, Python itself required key-order preservation in Python 3.7.

In CPython, the C implementation of the `dict` type itself is modified. I'm not sure exactly *how* (you can look into the details [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c)), but keeping an additional list in memory would likely be more efficient that doing the equivalent at the Python level, which is precisely what `OrderedDict` does. It's not even a Python `list` that holds the keys: it's a pure-Python linked list, so it's not surprising that the memory requirement is so large.

Answer (score -1):

From python 3.8 source code (see `self.__map`)

```
class _Link(object):
    __slots__ = 'prev', 'next', 'key', '__weakref__'

class OrderedDict(dict):
    'Dictionary that remembers insertion order'
    # An inherited dict maps keys to values.
    # The inherited dict provides __getitem__, __len__, __contains__, and get.
    # The remaining methods are order-aware.
    # Big-O running times for all methods are the same as regular dictionaries.

    # The internal self.__map dict maps keys to links in a doubly linked list.
    # The circular doubly linked list starts and ends with a sentinel element.
    # The sentinel element never gets deleted (this simplifies the algorithm).
    # The sentinel is in self.__hardroot with a weakref proxy in self.__root.
    # The prev links are weakref proxies (to prevent circular references).
    # Individual links are kept alive by the hard reference in self.__map.
    # Those hard references disappear when a key is deleted from an OrderedDict.

    def __init__(self, other=(), /, **kwds):
        '''Initialize an ordered dictionary.  The signature is the same as
        regular dictionaries.  Keyword argument order is preserved.
        '''
        try:
            self.__root
        except AttributeError:
            self.__hardroot = _Link()
            self.__root = root = _proxy(self.__hardroot)
            root.prev = root.next = root
            self.__map = {}
        self.__update(other, **kwds)
```

Comment: The question is with regards to the builtin `dict` type, not `collections.OrderedDict`, which is implemented differently.

Comment: @AlexWaygood - good catch. I thought the question was about OrderedDict ... Thanks.